# How to change script embed size?

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I have this code:

```
<script src="https://giscus.app/client.js"
        data-repo="?"
        data-repo-id="?"
        data-category="?”
        data-category-id="?"
        data-mapping="?"
        data-strict="?"
        data-reactions-enabled="?"
        data-emit-metadata="?"
        data-input-position="?"
        data-theme="?"
        data-lang="."
        crossorigin="?"
        async>
</script>
```

It's basically an embed that provides a comment box for people to comment on my blog posts.
But it's just too big to fit with my website’s design. How could I change its size?

[image: Embed]

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmK09.jpg)

I tried using `width: "size px"` and it didn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

"too big" is rather vague, in what way is it too big? Too wide? It looks like the giscus container will resize based on the size of the parent, so you can limit the width and height of the parent element and that will constrain giscus' size. If you need to resize elements inside the giscus iframe, you'll need to use its [custom theme functionality](https://github.com/giscus/giscus/blob/main/ADVANCED-USAGE.md#data-theme) to add a stylesheet that can apply rules to elements within the iframe.

Comment: how do i limit the parent’s size?

Comment: @Vicent , I assume you have an element somewhere that the chatbox renders into, on other sites using giscus there's something like `<div class="giscus"></div>`. You can wrap that in another div and apply CSS to that div. You could inline the css and do something like `<div style="max-width: 500px"><div class="giscus" /></div>` as an example.